# How to (re)create Recovery HD?

Tags: macos, recovery-hd

I have new macbook pro and I format whole drive to one partition and restore my backup (time machine).

Now I have no "Recovery HD" partition. How can i create it?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/26308588

1. Download [Recovery Partition Creator 3.8](http://musings.silvertooth.us/2014/07/recovery-partition-creator-3-8/)
2. Download Maverics through App Store
3. Cancel installation (cmd+Q)
4. Run Recovery Partition Creator
5. Follow instructions

Thanks all

Comment: Please don't just add a link, links may break rendering your answer useless. Your answer provides more value if you summarize the essential parts of the linked page

Comment: @patrix ok, done